# Action of a Lie group on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, group-actions

Let $G$ be a Lie group  which  acts on a manifold $M$. We say that $M$ is $G$-oriented if $M$ is oriented and the $G$-action preserves the orientation of $M$.

I'm not sure what does it mean that "the $G$-action preserves the orientation of $M$" ?

I think that if $\omega$ is a volume form on M which determine its orientation, then we say that the $G$-action preserves the orientation of $M$ if $g.\omega$ is in the same class of $\omega$, for all $g \in G$. Am I right ?

Comment: It simply means that $(g^*\omega)/\omega >0$ for all $g\in G$. You can also make a purely topological definition if the $G$-action is merely continuous by requiring that  $G$ acts trivially on $H^n_c(M)$, $n=dim(M)$.

Comment: Ok thanks @Moishe kohan !